# store socket client object in redis

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

i am new to nodejs and redis. i am facing issue with saving the socket client object in redis and then get it somewhere else to send the message to particular client (browser). I am able to store the socket client object into the redis and also i am getting the object back when only issue i am facing is that it looses the function send() which i want to use to send the message. Here is what i have done so far.

```
socket.io - version 2.1.1

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    // Set the redis option to the Redis client instance
    redis: {
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
        pubClient: pubClient,
        subClient: subClient,
    },
});
const createAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
const adapter = createAdapter({ pubClient, subClient });
io.adapter(adapter);
```

in socket.on(connection) method i am subscribing to the topic using

```
io.of('/').adapter.subClient.subscribe(value.toUpperCase());
```

and right after that i am setting the value to redis client, by doing something like this.

```
io.of('/').adapter.pubClient.set(value.toUpperCase(), CircularJSON.stringify(client), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log(`Saved client object for socket ${socket.id}`);
            }
        });
```

i am also listening to the subscribed events like below

```
io.of('/').adapter.subClient.on('message', (channel, message) => {
        const redisClient = io.of('/').adapter.pubClient;
        redisClient.get(channel, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                const socketData = CircularJSON.parse(data);  //this is the socket client object stored in the redis             


                socketData.send(JSON.parse(message));// here i am gettig .send() is not a function.

            }
        });
    });
```

i am publishing the message for above

```
io.of('/').adapter.subClient.on('message', (channel, message)
```

using

```
io.of('/').adapter.pubClient.publish(id.toUpperCase(), JSON.stringify(data));
```

Can you please provide me and exmaple of how can i get the send() method on the socketdata object?

What i have tried so far.

- I have tried to make a in memory sockt instance and update the properties to that one and use that updated socket object to send() the data
- tried to create new socket instance with the info from socket client object retrieved from redis client object.
- tried to make clone of the object using different methods by implementing send() before setting the client object into redis
- similar other implementations to make the retrieved socket object work with send() method.

Expecting: solution to be able to use send() on the retrieved socket client object from redis.

Comment: Thats simple not possible what you want. Redis can only store simple data types as strings. When you serialize the socket object you "simple" turn it into a string. You cant serialize methods/functions and store them inside of redis.

Comment: any walkaround this problem?